# selenium crashes: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do some data mining on a website. I am using selenium with webdriver inside a `for` loop. The problem is that my code crashes when I set it to wait for a time.

In the website you need to click on an image, which will send an order to give you the file. In the case of Firefox, you need to specify if you want to download or save it. This is already solved, however when it comes to moving to the next website is when crashes.

The problem is that the last line results in `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "D:path")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml")

for i in urls['tubicacion']:  
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, 
                           executable_path=r'path\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')

    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get(i)
    elemen = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GOOGLE"]').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(0)
    follow = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//*[@id="GOOGLE"]'))).click().close()
```

I have also tried the last line like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//*[@id="GOOGLE"]').text)).click().close()
```

Comment: Dont do .text !! you have to click on the element, not need to extract text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `By.XPATH` is with tuple

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GOOGLE"]')))
```

Comment: This raises this problem `^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @user143853 Not this line, I checked it. Where exactly is the error?

Comment: There, if I make `By.XPATH` a tuple, it raises that error.

Comment: @user143853 Did you change anything? added or removed something? post the line that gives you the error.

Comment: Wait, I copy-paste your line and this is I what I get now:

    `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException`

Comment: @user143853 are you sure you want `invisibility_of_element_located` and not `visibility_of_element_located`? you want to click on it after all, you can't do it if the element is invisible.

Comment: This is the website [link](https://presas.conagua.gob.mx/inventario/tubicacion.aspx?DSP,1). 

If I use `visibility_of_element_located` it works perfectly. However, it opens a new browser each time and I am trying to download 600,000 files. 

So what I need is to close the browser and open it again. Or, keep it open and just change the url and download the file and so on.

Comment: @user143853 This is an entirely other question, it should be posted as a new question and not in the comments.

Comment: Ok, I will do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem, remove .text. I also remove .close

```
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//*[@id="GOOGLE"]'))).click()
```

Comment: I received this message `File "<ipython-input-43-a20e9012b89b>", line 26, in <module>
    follow = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//*[@id="GOOGLE"]'))).click()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`